# Showing that a function is pointwise convergent

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence, pointwise-convergence

[image]
Here is how I answered  the question. Could you please say what is not correct if it's incorrect?

Taking $ϵ = 1$ in the definition of the uniform convergence, we find that there exists $N ∈ N $such that $|f_{n}(x) − f(x)| < 1$ for all $x ∈ A $ if $p > q$. Choose some $n > N$. Then, since $f_n$ is bounded, there is a constant $Mn ≥ 0$ such that $|f_n(x)| ≤ Mn$ for all $x ∈ A$. It follows that $|f(x)| ≤ |f(x) − f_n(x)| + |f_n(x)| < 1 + Mn$ for all $x ∈ A$, meaning that $f$ is bounded on $A $(by $1 + Mn$). 
If $ 0 < x ≤ 1$, then $fn(x) = 0$ for all $ n ≥ 1/x$, so $ f_n(x) → 0$ as $n → ∞$; and if $x = 0$, then $f_n(x) = 0$ for all $n$, so $f_n(x) → 0 $ also. It follows that $f_n → 0$ pointwise on $[0, 1]$. This is the case even though  $||f_n|| = n → ∞ $ as $n → ∞$. Thus, a pointwise convergent sequence of functions need not be bounded, even if it converges to zero. As the boundaries are not set within the exclusive set of range values that satisfies the condition of $p,q>0 $ thus the convergence of the range uniformly sets on the interval of the $[0.01, 1] $

Comment: Saying a function is pointwise convergent doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 1):

Remark: above you have written that $f_n(x) = 0$ for all $n \geq 1/x$. But
$f_n(x) = n^p x \exp(-n^q x) > 0$ for all $x > 0$. To prove the uniform convergence it is sufficient  to use the following  equivalence:
$$ f_{n} \rightarrow f \; (\mbox{uniformly}) \iff \| f_n - f \|_{\infty} \rightarrow 0 \; \mbox{when } n \rightarrow + \infty. $$ In your case,
we have $\|f_n\|_{\infty} = n^{p - q} e^{-1}$ which goes to zero when $n \rightarrow + \infty$. So, if  $q > p$ we have uniform convergence. On the other hand, if  $p >  q$, then $n^{p - q} \rightarrow + \infty$ as $n \rightarrow + \infty$ (If $p = q$, $\|f_n\|_{\infty}  = \frac{1}{e}$). Hence, in this case, using the above equivalence, we conclude  that the  convergence cannot be uniform.